# external swf load into main swf

Tags: actionscript, flash

I need to load exteranal swf into my main swf into a dispay object in this main swf. how do it? i like to play gta!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`loadMovie`](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary537.html) function for ActionScript 1 or 2.

Or if you are using ActionScript 3 then use the [`loader`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html) function

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the greensock classes:
http://www.greensock.com/

They've got some great tools for loading swfs or generally loading assets , very useful if the loaded swf is loading other assets and you want to keep track of the overall loading progress.